# How to do FQL NOW()+1HOUR?

Tags: facebook, time, facebook-fql

Here's my FQL:

```
$fql = 'SELECT eid FROM event WHERE eid IN (...) AND start_time>now()'
```

I want something like...

```
$fql = 'SELECT eid FROM event WHERE eid IN (...) AND start_time-1hour>now()'
```

or...

```
$fql = 'SELECT eid FROM event WHERE eid IN (...) AND start_time>now()+1hour'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just compute the time u want in your program code then outputting to fql query. This way you won't need a function in fql to subtract or add date time.

Enable ISO Time for events in App Settings (Advanced). Then use the following value for now:

```
$now = date("c", time()+60*60);
```

Comment: In that case please tell me how to figure out **now()** in PHP such that I won't have time-zone issues.

Comment: Hi, you can use php DateTime: $datetime = new DateTime('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'); echo $datetime->format(DateTime::ISO8601);

Comment: Use DateTime::ISO8601 as Facebook event table use time representation in ISO8601 format. The input time string in new DateTime(...) should be your local time. The output datetime string will be ur localtime with offset from UTC time.

Comment: Thank you. If you're right, I think `$now = date("c", time()+60*60);` should work